# Как запустить gcc, установленный из исходников?

Tags: gcc

Я установил версию компилятора gcc-4.6.2 из исходников,

```
tar xzf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz                                                          
cd gcc-4.6.2                                                               
./contrib/download_prerequisites                        
cd ..                                                                       
mkdir objdir                                                                
cd objdir                                                     
$PWD/../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.6.2 --enable languages=c,c++,fortran,go                                             
make                                                              
make install
```

однако при проверке версии gcc -version указана версия 4.7.2, установленная ранее. Каким образом переключиться между этими версиями?

Comment: Вероятно вам нужно запускать gcc из $HOME/gcc-4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

указать в PATH первым путь до своего собранного компилятора

```
PATH=$HOME/gcc-4.6.2/bin-наверное:$PATH;export $PATH
```